# Can't format a double to so that it prints 2 digits after decimal separator

Tags: java, arrays, format, printf

I'm trying to format a double so that it only prints 2 digits behind the decimal separator. All my variables are doubles and the odd thing is that it formats `aflossingen[i]` just fine and doesn't give an error, but if i try to format `interesten[i]` and `uitstaandeLening[i]` the same way it just gives this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
```

There are also no String-type variables or anything in my code. I just can't see what the problem is.

Here is all my code

```
package pe2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PE2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double beginKapitaal = 0;
    double jaarlijkseRente = 0;
    double rente = 0;
    double afbetalingsDuur = 0;
    int aantalJaren = 0;
    double annuiteit = 0;
    double interest;
    double aflossing;

    double[] uitstaandeLening;
    double[] interesten;
    double[] aflossingen;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5;) {
        System.out.println("Wat is het beginkapitaal?");
        beginKapitaal = input.nextDouble();
        if (beginKapitaal <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Het beginkapitaal moet groter zijn dan 0");
        } else {
            i = 5;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5;) {
        System.out.println("Wat is de jaarlijkse rente?");
        jaarlijkseRente = input.nextDouble();

        if (jaarlijkseRente <= 0) {
            System.out.println("De jaarlijkse rente moet groter zijn dan 0");
        } else {
            i = 5;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5;) {
        System.out.println("In hoeveel jaar zal de lening afbetaald worden?");
        afbetalingsDuur = input.nextDouble();
        aantalJaren = (int) afbetalingsDuur + 1;
        if (afbetalingsDuur <= 0) {
            System.out.println("De afbetalingsduur moet groter zijn dan 0");
        } else {
            i = 5;
        }
    }

    rente = jaarlijkseRente / 100;

    input.close();

    annuiteit = beginKapitaal * (rente / (1 - (1 / Math.pow(rente + 1, afbetalingsDuur))));

    System.out.printf("Beginkapitaal: " + "%.2f", beginKapitaal);
    System.out.printf("\nIntrest: " + "%.2f", jaarlijkseRente);
    System.out.printf("\nAfbetalingsduur in jaren: " + "%.1f", afbetalingsDuur);
    System.out.printf("\nAnnuïteit: " + "%.2f", annuiteit);

    uitstaandeLening = new double[aantalJaren];
    interesten = new double[aantalJaren];
    aflossingen = new double[aantalJaren];
    //interest = beginKapitaal * rente;
    //aflossing = annuiteit - interest;

    for (int i = 0; i < aantalJaren; i++) {

        uitstaandeLening[i] = beginKapitaal - aflossingen[i];
        interesten[i] = beginKapitaal * rente;
        aflossingen[i] = annuiteit - interesten[i];

        if (i == 0) {
            System.out.printf("\n\nJaar" + "\tUitstaande lening" + "\tInteresten" + "\t\tAflossing");
        } else if (i == 1) {
            System.out.printf("\nJaar " + i + "\t" + uitstaandeLening[i] + "\t\t" + "%.2f" , interesten[i] + "\t\t" + "%.2f",
                    aflossingen[i]);
            beginKapitaal = beginKapitaal - aflossingen[i];
        } else {

            System.out.printf("\nJaar " + i + "\t" + uitstaandeLening[i] + "\t" + interesten[i] + "\t" + "%.2f",
                    aflossingen[i]);

            beginKapitaal = beginKapitaal - aflossingen[i];
        }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: You are adding a format in the param. `System.out.printf("\nJaar " + i + "\t" + uitstaandeLening[i] + "\t\t" + "%.2f" , interesten[i] + "\t\t" + "%.2f",
                    aflossingen[i]);` should be `System.out.printf("\nJaar " + i + "\t" + uitstaandeLening[i] + "\t\t" + "%.2f"  + "\t\t" + "%.2f" , interesten[i],
                    aflossingen[i]);` ... among other issues.

Comment: That doesn't format it :/
And what are the other issues then?

Comment: Please add expected output vs output you are getting. `uitstandeLening` won't be formatted, because you didn't tell printf to do so. The others should be formatted. Try: `System.out.printf("\nJaar %d\t %.2f \t\t %.2f \t\t %.2f" , i, uitstaandeLening[i], interesten[i], aflossingen[i]);`

Comment: As a sidenote: Handling monetary values, you should probably use BigDecimal instead of double.

Comment: Can you please post the code you used to produce that output?

Comment: Now I made it work with the code you posted here. 
So how comes it works now? Do i have to format it at the beginning of the line?

Comment: See my answer. I tried to explain it in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("\nJaar " + i + "\t" + uitstaandeLening[i] + "\t\t" + "%.2f" , interesten[i] + "\t\t" + "%.2f",
                    aflossingen[i]);
```

Let's have a closer look:

This is the string you tell `printf` to format: `"\nJaar " + i + "\t" + uitstaandeLening[i] + "\t\t" + "%.2f"`

Mind that `uitstaandeLening` is completely unformatted, it will be autoboxed and the default formatting will be used.

This is your first parameter: `interesten[i] + "\t\t" + "%.2f"`

This is illegal because you are trying to have printf format a string with the "f" formatter. Concatenation with string makes the whole object a string.
So for example `""+someIntegerVar` is of type String after it has been evaluated. That's why `interesten` will also be autoboxed and default-formatted.

And finally the second parameter has no formatter in your template (only the topmost string will be evaluated for formatters, not the parameters recursively).

The correct line would be:

```
System.out.printf("\nJaar %d\t %.2f \t\t %.2f \t\t %.2f" , i, uitstaandeLening[i], interesten[i], aflossingen[i]);
```

All formatters in the template string, then just numeric parameters. You can also have string or date params, of course.

Additionally, I recommend using [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Double will introduce rounding errors, that may be significant when working with money.

Also, you should avoid concatentating strings with "+". `"\t\t" + "%.2f"` for example is suboptimal. It is just a micro-tuning, but generally a good rule of thumb.

Oracle has also a tutorial concerning number formatting: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: Thank you very very much, really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

This is working, hope this will help:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class TestDouble{

    private static DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double input = 32.123456;
        System.out.println("double : " + input);
        System.out.println("double : " + df2.format(input));
    }

}
```

Comment: i don't why its not working for you...But here Its working.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer.

String.format needs Object, not double..
so you need a "new Doutble( double value)"

```
double d=1.234;
System.out.println( String.format("%.2f", new Double(d)));
```

Comment: thanks.. autoboxing works.  There's  no   "String.format()"  that's the problem ^^